# Using stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Supposing i have a stored procedure fun(input, @val), and i want to call it repeatedly, in a select. I tried like this:

```
select name, @val
from table
where {condition}
group by name
```

I need that @val be updated somewhere in the statement with:

```
 call fun(name, @val)
```

As the value of @val depends on the current "iteration".

How do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function that returns a value rather than using a stored procedure. Link to function creation syntax - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: In that case, modify the stored procedure so that it would return the value for all possible input values and store it in a temp table. Later u can join with that temp table on that input value and get the result.